# Background of PHP and HTML need to allocate differently in VS Code

Tags: php, html, background

In my previous IDE, the background of PHP and HTML was highlighted differently and visually it was very convenient. How to do this in [VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MlDQ.png), I did not understand.

https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/1839

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes

Comment: Are you suggesting that I create my own theme?

Comment: That link talks about using already available themes, downloading new to you themes, or creating you own.